# Why does my multivariate LSTM keeps predicting zeroes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

My time series data has 2 features:

```
                 0         1
1/22/20      555.0      17.0
1/23/20      654.0      18.0
1/24/20      941.0      26.0
1/25/20     1434.0      42.0
1/26/20     2118.0      56.0
...            ...       ...
5/3/20   3506729.0  247470.0
5/4/20   3583055.0  251537.0
5/5/20   3662691.0  257239.0
5/6/20   3755341.0  263831.0
5/7/20   3845718.0  269567.0

[107 rows x 2 columns]
```

I am trying to create a multivariate LSTM to make predictions for each of the columns. After processing the data the train and test arrays have the following shapes:

```
Legend:  (samples, time steps, features)
x_train: (67, 4, 2)
y_train: (67, 2)
x_test:  (26, 4, 2)
y_test:  (26, 2)
```

Here is the model definition:

```py
forecast_horizon = 4
feature_n = 2
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=50, restore_best_weights=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(forecast_horizon, feature_n)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(feature_n))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping], validation_split=0.2)
```

The predictions are full of zeros. The output of `test_predictions = model.predict(x_test)` is:

```
[[0.00839295 0.007538  ]
 [0.         0.        ]
 [0.00946797 0.00663883]
 [0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.        ]
  ...        ...
 [0.0007435  0.        ]
 [0.00116019 0.00032421]
 [0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.        ]]
```

When looking at the training loss it seems that the model is not learning very well.
[image]

Is this a matter of simply training the model for longer and adjusting its hyperparameters or is there something else that could be affecting this? How can I implement a proper multivariate LSTM?

Comment: Did you scale your y before training?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Yes, I took the ln of the data then differenced it three times before giving it to the network.

Comment: don't forget to reverse scale when you make a prediction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch size of 1 means your model weights are being adjusted based on 1 observation rather than optimizing for a handful of observations. Common batch sizes are between 16 and 32 but can be adjusted depending on the model.

LSTM models also require thousands of observations, so get more training data if possible

Architectures can also vary so it's best to try a number of different approaches and see what works best. You can find more info here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/